# Postgres Trigger Function Dynamic Column Concat TG_TABLE_NAME

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, database-trigger

I want to know if it's possible to do something like this on Postgres 11 in a trigger function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "searchs"."handle_content" ( ) 
  RETURNS trigger 
AS $BODY$ 
BEGIN
  UPDATE table 
      set test = 1
  WHERE item_id = NEW.format('%I_id',TG_TABLE_NAME);
END;
$BODY$
```

The primary key on table change, so i need to concat with the table name

```
NEW.format('%I_id',TG_TABLE_NAME)
```

Comment: Do you want to update a different table than the one for which the trigger is defined?

Comment: Yes I have 5 triggers on 5 tables, When something change, I update another table

Comment: And I don't want to use 5 functions to do the same, i can do it, but i do not want because 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved with CASE, but I still wish to know if it's possible to convert to an array record type, or access it dynamic.